# Why my useState in useEffect is not rerendering?

Tags: reactjs

I tried a lot of different solutions and none worked. The problem is that I'm calling a function inside useEffect, the function is working well, the variable is getting the result I want but when I'm going to set the state, nothing happens but the state update and I can see in react tools extension.

This is my code, I'm receiving as props cart that is a array of objects [{id, quantity}]

fetchDetail is a simple function that calls an api and It's working

I saw some answers saying that the useEffect does not recognize the update so I't don't rerender but I don't know why.

```
const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);


  async function mapIds() {
    const result = [];

    await Promise.all(
      cart.map((product) => {
        fetchDetail(product.id).then((data) =>
          result.push({
            id: data.id,
            title: data.title,
            quantity: product.quantity,
            thumbnail: data.thumbnail,
            price: data.price,
          })
        );
      })
    );

    setItems(result);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    mapIds();
  }, [cart]);

  return (
    <>
      <section id="cart-container">
        <h1>Carrinho de compras</h1>
        {items.length > 0 ? (
          items.map((item) => (
            <div>
              <p key={item.id}>{item.title}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>Carrinho vazio</p>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: cart in the first render is only a [], and after I click on button It will pass a value [{id, quantity}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promises aren't being awaited because `Promise.all` isn't seeing them:

```
cart.map((product) => {
  // This callback to .map() doesn't return anything
  fetchDetail(product.id).then((data) =>
    //...
  )
});
```

The callback to `.map()` needs to *return* the `Promise`:

```
cart.map((product) => {
  // return the Promise...
  return fetchDetail(product.id).then((data) =>
    //...
  )
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot David! Hahaha I was sure that would be a simple error. Solved! Thanks!!!!